# Need help to merge two sql tables when one contains ids and second contains names associated to that id

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I have 2 tables in MySQL. 
One has transactions with important columns where each row has Debit account ID and Credit account ID. I have second table which contains Account name and special number associated to Account ID. I want somehow to try sql query which will take data from transactions table and assign account name and account number from second table.

I tried doing everything using two query , one would get transactions and second one would get account details and then I did iterate over dataframe and assigned everything one by one which doesn't seem to be good idea

```
    query = "SELECT  tr_id, tr_date, description, dr_acc, cr_acc, amount, currency, currency_rate, document, comment FROM transactions WHERE " \
            "company_id = {} {} and deleted = 0 {} LIMIT {}, {}".format(
        company_id, filter, sort, sn, en)

    df = ncon.getDF(query)

    df.insert(4, 'dr_name', '')
    df.insert(6, 'cr_name', '')

    data = tuple(list(set(df['dr_acc'].values.tolist() + df['cr_acc'].values.tolist())))

    query = "SELECT account_number, acc_id, account_name FROM tb_accounts WHERE company_id = {} and deleted = 0 and acc_id in {}".format(
        company_id, data)

    df_accs = ncon.getDF(query)

    for index, row in df_accs.iterrows():
        acc = str(row['acc_id'])
        ac = row['account_number']
        nm = row['account_name']

        indx = df.index[df['dr_acc'] == acc].tolist()
        df.at[indx, 'dr_acc'] = ac
        df.at[indx, 'dr_name'] = nm

        indx = df.index[df['cr_acc'] == acc].tolist()
        df.at[indx, 'cr_acc'] = ac
        df.at[indx, 'cr_name'] = nm
```

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want to combine the SQL tables or you are trying to conduct a query on an account_number, and if so, what is your expected output and the format you want that output in?

Comment: I want to output account details. deal is that in one table I have account ID in two column one is debit one is credit . and in another table I have ID, Account Name, Account Number and want to somehow join output but queries which I tried like INNER JOIN somehow gave me bunch of errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for, I think, is a [SQL JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) statement.

Taking a crack at writing a query that *might* work based on your code:

```
    query = '''
SELECT transactions.tr_id,
       transactions.tr_date, 
       transactions.description, 
       transactions.dr_acc,
       transactions.cr_acc,
       transactions.amount,
       transactions.currency,
       transactions.currency_rate,
       transactions.document,
       transactions.comment
FROM transactions INNER JOIN tb_accounts ON tb_accounts.acc_id = transactions.acc_id
WHERE 
        transactions.company_id = {} AND
        tb_accounts.company_id = {} AND
        transactions.deleted = 0 AND
        tb_accounts.deleted = 0
ORDER BY transactions.tr_id
LIMIT 10;'''
```

The above query will, roughly, present query results with all the fields listed from the two tables for each pair of rows where the `acc_id` is the same.

NOTE, the query above will probably not have very good performance. SQL JOIN statements must be written with care, but I wrote it above in a way that's easy to understand, so as to illustrate the power of the JOIN.

You should as a matter of habit NEVER try to program something when you could use a join instead. As long as you take care to [write a join properly so that it can be efficient](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-mysql/9780596101718/ch04.html), the MySQL engine will beat your python code for performance almost every time.

Comment: Thats perfect, thank you very much, got the idea now with the syntax and logic.

Answer (score 0):

sort two dataframe and use merge for merging 2data frame

```
df1 = df1.sort_values(['dr_acc'], ascending=True)
df2 = df2.sort_values(['acc_id'], ascending=True)

 merge2df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer',
                     left_on=['dr_acc'], right_on=['acc_id'])
```

I assumed df1 is 1st query data set and df2 is 2nd query data set

sql query

```
   '''SELECT  tr_id, tr_date, 
    description, 
    dr_acc, cr_acc,
    amount, currency,
    currency_rate, 
    document,
   account_number, acc_id, account_name
     comment FROM transactions left join
     tb_accounts on transactions.dr_acc=tb_accounts.account_number'''
```

Comment: Thats correct about df1 and df2 but is it possible to do that inside query?

Comment: @SandroShubladze yes possible in sql  as well